# Get value of a gpio without using linux API. Is there a way in assembly code?

Tags: c, embedded, assemblies, gpio

I'm writing a routine in ARM-assembly-code and I have to access a gpio. I can't use the function gpio_get_value from the linux API. ¿Anyone could tell me an alternative way to get the value, either in C or assembly?

Comment: Why can't you use the Linux API? Why assembly language? Is this for a bootstrap program? Have you consulted the datasheet for the SoC? Look for a section on the GPIO or PIO (Parallel Input Output) controller. If you can't use the Linux API, then does that mean that the MMU has not been enabled, and you need to use physical addresses? Have you simply looked at your arch's implementation of [**gpio_get_value()** in the Linux source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=gpio_get_value) as a start?

Comment: Yes I just read and write the corresponding memory position.

Answer (score 2):

There is more that one ARM architecture and instruction set, so you may have to be more specific.  Moreover GPIO is not defined by the ARM core, but is implementation specific, so you'd have to specify the exact device (and it would necessarily be different for each device).

If you know the exact device, you only need to read the user reference for the part.  GPIO is normally memory-mapped, so it is normally simply a case of reading the appropriate memory address.  For a part with an MMU (normal on Linux), the GPIO may or may not be mapped to a virtual address (I am no Linux expert).

Comment: *"GPIO is normally memory-mapped"* -- For ARM, there is no I/O address space, so all device registers are memory mapped.  Your point about *"may or may not be mapped to a virtual address'* is salient.

Comment: @sawdust:  It was intended a s a general point rather than ARM specific, but even on an ARM platform, it is conceivable that GPIO might be implemented by an off-chip I/O expander, FPGA or multiplexer for example, and may not then be directly memory mapped.